# Resizing UIModalPresentationFormSheet on iOS 8

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, xcode6

I'm trying to resize an UIViewController presented as a modal on iPad using UIModalPresentationFormSheet, and although I got it working on <= iOS 7, I can't on iOS 8

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For iOS 8 you have to set "preferredContentSize" property, but for iOS 7 and older you have to set the superview.frame property.

Example code:

```
UIViewController* modalController = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
modalController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
modalController.modalPresentationStyle =  UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

CGPoint frameSize = CGPointMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width*0.95f, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height*0.95f);
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

// Resizing for iOS 8
modalController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(frameSize.x, frameSize.y); 
// Resizing for <= iOS 7
modalController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake((screenWidth - frameSize.x)/2, (screenHeight - frameSize.y)/2, frameSize.x, frameSize.y);

UIViewController *vc = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
[vc presentViewController:modalController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: sometimes this only works if you set the resizing *after* you present the view controller

Comment: not work for iOS7 with XCode5 for me. works on iOS8 with XCode6

Comment: I had to add this to my VC's viewDidLoad to make it work. Setting in viewWillAppear was too late..
`if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setPreferredContentSize:)])`
`{ self.preferredContentSize = originalFrame.size;}`

Comment: Great answer , it worked for me.
modalController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(frameSize.x, frameSize.y);

Comment: i had to add both preferredContentSize & view.superview.frame to work

Answer (score 9):

this depends on if you're using UIPopoverPresentationController or UIPresentationController. You can try setting the "preferredContentSize" property to be your new content size (the "contentSizeForViewInPopover" property is deprecated in iOS 8).

Comment: did this work for you? Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: I finally performed a workaround by creating a custom view. I'm gonna mark your answer as valid anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

To resize a `UIViewController`'s view, when it is already presented with `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` modal presentation style and is visible, use for iOS 8+:

```
self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    [self.presentationController.containerView setNeedsLayout];
    [self.presentationController.containerView layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```